# Erro ao executar: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $

Tags: android

Alguém sabe como resolver esse erro? Não sei o motivo, meu projeto estava normal, mas deu queda de energia e o pc desligou direto, após isso não consigo mais executa-lo no celular, ocorre esse erro aí:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithInstantRunForDebug'.
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $

Answer (score 5):

[RESOLVIDO]

Consegui, fui na aba build->Clean Project 
E então tentei executar dnv e funcionou

(Se alguém poder me explicar melhor oque ocorreu eu agradeço)

Comment: Sua resposta me ajudou, aqui também teve uma queda de luz, mais pelo motivo que na primeira vez que compilei foi pensei que não tinha nada haver , tava procurando erro com meu servidor ,Valeu.

Comment: Aqui travou o notebook precisei reiniciar forçando quando voltou deu esse erro, agora dei um clean e está tudo Ok! Valeu